# How to manually add an abbreviation to ReSharper abbreviation list?

Tags: resharper, abbreviation

ReSharper offers to add abbreviations to a list, (per computer, per solution team-shared, or per solution personal).  But sometimes it doesn't automatically understand which part of identifier comprise an abbreviation. I'd like to be able to manually add a word I need to ReSharper abbreviation list. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding what you are wanting to do...

This appears to work for **ReSharper 2019.2.2** in **Visual Studio 2019**.

1. Click *Extensions* on tool bar
2. Hover over *ReSharper*
3. Click *Options...*
4. Open *Code Editing*
5. Open *C#*
6. Click *Naming Style*
7. Click *Advanced*
8. Enter abbreviations in *Abbreviations* text box at the bottom
9. Click *OK* then *Save*